# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Не знаю(,) почему, мы подчинились этому приказу" — нужна ли запятая перед "почему"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед "почему " нужно, после - нет. Предложение сложноподчиненное, ставим запятую на границе частей.

Comment: Согласен с таким ответом, но, возможно, это предложение построено немного неудачно. Может быть, автор хотел подчеркнуть, логически выделить слово "почему" (причина подчинения приказу), и тогда запятую следует поставить после "почему", но при этом добавить союз "но": Не знаю почему, но мы подчинились этому приказу.